# sqlite3.OperationalError: table inventory has no column named car_make. when database has column

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

i keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\computing project\add to db.py", line 114, in get_items
    C.execute(sql ,vari)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table inventory has no column named car_make
```

when attempting to insert values into mydatabse taken from tkinter

i have tried changing the names of the columns in order to see if that would solve the issue bit nothing has changed, i am using db browser in order to edit my database

```
from tkinter import* 
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("G:\computing project\database of cars.db")
C = conn.cursor()
import tkinter.messagebox


 def get_items(self,*args,**kwargs):  #this function gets the items from the entry boxes

        self.carmake= self.carmake_e.get()
        self.carmodel= self.carmodel_e.get()
        self.regi= self.regi_e.get()
        self.colour= self.colour_e.get()
        self.cost= self.cost_e.get()
        self.tcost= self.tcost_e.get()
        self.sellprice= self.sellprice_e.get()
        self.assumedprofit= self.assumedprofit_e.get()

        self.assumedprofit= float(self.sellprice)- float(self.tcost)


        if self.carmake == '' or self.carmodel == '' == self.colour == '':
            print ("WRONG")
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("error","please enter values for car make, model and colour")

        else:
            print("solid m8 ")
            sql = "INSERT INTO inventory(car_make,car_model,registration_plate,colour,cost,total_cost,selling_price,assumed_profit) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            vari=(self.carmake,self.carmodel,self.regi,self.colour,self.cost,self.tcost,self.sellprice,self.assumedprofit)
            C.execute(sql ,vari)
               # C.execute(sql(self.name,self.carmake,self.carmodel,self.regi,self.colour,self.cost,self.tcost,self.sellprice,self.assumedprofit))
            conn.commit()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("success","succesfully added to databse")
```

Comment: That's a pretty firm error message.  When you use your db browser, are you sure it's the same database the code is using?  `G:\computing project\database of cars.db`

Comment: 100%  I don't have any other databases I'm not sure what it could be